# AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'year'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
d1 = datetime.strptime(self.current_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
d2 = datetime.strptime(self.dob, "%Y-%m-%d")

current_age = (d1 - d2).year
```

Running this code give the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Answer (score 29):

As per the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), a `timedelta` counts `days`, not years.  So try something like `(d1 - d2).days / 365.25`.

Comment: @SupreethKV: You're welcome.  You should go back to the questions you've asked here before and "accept" an answer for each one by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  You've asked many questions but never accepted an answer so far.

Answer (score 4):

Calculating the difference between 2 dates returns a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) (`datetime.timedelta`) such as `(d1 - d2)` in your sample code *("A timedelta object represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times.")*. Available from this are `.days`, `.seconds` and `.microseconds` (only). A `timedelta` isn't anchored to particular years so it doesn't provide `.years` since the number of leap years can only be accurately counted once a start date is known (`timedelta` doesn't have this information). Using the Python REPL,

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2021,1,1) - datetime.date(2020,1,1)
datetime.timedelta(days=366)
>>> datetime.date(2022,1,1) - datetime.date(2021,1,1)
datetime.timedelta(days=365)
```

For an exact answer take the original dates' `year` values and then use their `month` and `day` values to work out whether the subject's birthday has occurred this year or not. Adapting your sample code and omitting reference to the class you're clearly using (you don't provide the code for that so it's confusing to include it),

```
from datetime import date

d1 = date.today()
d2 = date(2000, 1, 1)  # Example date

current_age = d1.year - d2.year
if (d1.month, d1.day) < (d2.month, d2.day):
    current_age = current_age - 1  # Not had birthday yet
print(current_age)
```

Alternatively use the `dateutil` module's [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) which is aware of years. For example,

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

d1 = date.today()
d2 = date(2000, 1, 1)  # Example date

current_age = relativedelta(d1, d2).years
print(current_age)
```